# CodeIgniter Search function

Tags: php, sql, database, search, codeigniter-3

I can't get this right..

In **view file** (view_searchlog.php):

```
<div class="form-group">
         <form class="form-inline" action="<?php echo base_url(); ?>index.php/search/accsearch" method="post">
        <select class="form-control" name="field">
            <option selected="selected" disabled="disabled" value="">Filter By</option>
            <option value="subjName">Subject</option>
            <option value="homeaddress">Location</option>
            <option value="lname">Last Name</option>
        </select>
        <input class="form-control" type="text" name="search" value="" placeholder="Find..">
        <input class="btn btn-default" type="submit" name="filter" value="Search">
    </form>
        </div>
    </div>
        </div>
<div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-6">
    <h2 class="sub-header">Search Results</h2>
    </div>

    <div class="row">
  <div class="col-sm-12 col-md-8"><hr/>
      <?php echo $this->session->flashdata('nores'); ?>
               <?php foreach ($users as $user): ?>
    <div class="thumbnail">
      <img src="..." alt="...">
      <div class="caption">
        <h3><?=$user->name;?></h3>
        <p><?=$user->homeaddress;?></p>
        <p><?=$user->mobileNum;?></p>
        <p><a href="#" class="btn btn-primary" role="button">Request</a> <a href="#" class="btn btn-default" role="button">View Profile</a></p>
      </div>
    </div>
              <?php endforeach; ?>
  </div>
</div>
```

In **db**, I have **tables**: *users*, *account*, and *subjects* where:

**subjects**

```
subjID | subjName | accID
------ | -------- | -----
1      | Math     | 1
```

**account**

```
 accID | subjID   | userID
------ | -------- | -----
1      | 1        | 1
```

**users**

```
userID | userName | accID
------ | -------- | -----
1      | foo      | 1
```

I have the ff code for my search **controller**:

```
if (isset($filter) && !empty($search)) {
            $data['users'] = $this->model_search->searchTutor($field, $search);
        }
        elseif (($filter == 'subjName') && !empty($search)) {
            $data['users'] = $this->model_search->searchBySubj($field, $search);
        }
        elseif (isset($filter) && empty($search)) {
            $data['users'] = $this->model_search->getlist($field);
        }
        elseif (isset($filter) && ($search == 0)) {
            $this->session->set_flashdata('nores','<div class="alert text-center">No result matched your search.</div>');
            redirect('search/index');
        }
```

Then I try to search for a Subject Name that is not in db

So it's supposed to enter 2nd elseif `->searchBySubj();` function

In search **model**:

```
public function searchTutor($field, $search)
    {
        $this->db->like($field, $search);
        $this->db->order_by($field);
        $query = $this->db->get('users');
        return $query->result();
    }

    public function searchBySubj($field, $search)
    {
        $this->db->query("SELECT id as Userid, accID as AccID, subjID as subid, subjName as sname FROM users userT INNER JOIN account accT ON id = accID INNER JOIN subjects ON accID = subjID;");
        $query = $this->db->get('users', 'ASC');
        return $query->result();
    }
```

But this appears:

```
A Database Error Occurred
Error Number: 1054
Unknown column 'subjName' in 'where clause'
SELECT * FROM `users` WHERE `subjName` LIKE '%mathematics%' ESCAPE '!' ORDER BY `subjName`
```

The 3rd elseif runs when I try to search for a location and it gives me all the list

Then I tried to search a location not in db but the last condition does not display the flashdata

I put `<?php echo $this->session->flashdata('nores'); ?>` in view (above)

Overall, I just want to search by Subject Name with tables that I have. Also, display flashdata if no record matches.

How should these be properly done? What causes these errors?

What am I missing?

excuse my bad coding here, please help me with this one..

Answer (score 1):

Remove the code mentioned below as its pointing it to the users table only.You can use only for active records.

```
 $query = $this->db->get('users', 'ASC');
```

Below is the right approach

```
$query = $this->db->query("YOUR QUERY");
return $query->result();
```

Comment: @ppatil27 added new knowledge to me thanks for that. But what I don't understand is why it won't read this line `elseif (($filter == 'subjName') && !empty($search)) {
            $data['users'] = $this->model_search->searchBySubj($field, $search);
        }` I already tried changing the query and accessing directly to subjects table but the error is still `Unknown column 'subjName' in 'where clause'

SELECT * FROM **users** WHERE subjName LIKE '%mathematics%' ESCAPE '!' ORDER BY subjName`

Comment: It only comes if above condition gets fail. so try giving $filter=='someName' in first condition too.

Comment: Yes. I have also found another solution for my code. @Pramod Patil Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

In your query, you are looking for the column `subjName` which is in the `Subject` table:

```
SELECT * FROM `users` WHERE `subjName` LIKE '%mathematics%' ESCAPE '!' ORDER BY `subjName`
```

You would need to join the subject table to access the subjName column:

```
SELECT * FROM `users` INNER JOIN account accT ON id = accID INNER JOIN subjects ON accID = subjID WHERE `subjName` LIKE '%mathematics%' ESCAPE '!' ORDER BY `subjName`
```

(This is the join query from your code with the added conditions, it may or not work)